# How do I retrieve a string from a PWSTR after a Win32 function succeeds?

Tags: winapi, rust

I would like to get my username in an `std::String` using the windows-rs crate.

```
use bindings::Windows::Win32::{
    System::WindowsProgramming::GetUserNameW,
    Foundation::PWSTR,
};

fn main() {
    let mut pcbbuffer: u32 = 255;
    let mut helper: u16 = 0;
    let lpbuffer = PWSTR(&mut helper);
    println!("lpbuffer: {:?}\npcbbuffer: {:?}", lpbuffer, pcbbuffer);
    unsafe {
        let success = GetUserNameW(lpbuffer, &mut pcbbuffer);
        println!("GetUserNameW succeeded: {:?}\nlpbuffer: {:?}\npcbbuffer: {:?}", success.as_bool(), lpbuffer, pcbbuffer);
    }
}
```

produces the output:

```
lpbuffer: PWSTR(0xca20f5f76e)
pcbbuffer: 255
GetUserNameW succeeded: true 
lpbuffer: PWSTR(0x7200650073)
pcbbuffer: 5
```

The username is "user" that's 4 + 1 terminating character = 5 which is good. I also see the `GetUserNameW` function succeeded and the pointer to the string changed.

What are the next steps?

Comment: Before moving forward, you need to take a step back. As written, you're asking the API to write into a buffer of size one, but tell it, that the buffer were 255 elements long. That's not going to end well.

Comment: According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getusernamew i should aim at 256+1, i tried with 4, failed, 5 succeeds.

Comment: Sure, but you're writing into `helper`, which is a single `u16` value.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code as posted works by coincidence alone. It sports a spectacular buffer overflow, hardly what you'd want to see in Rust code. Specifically, you're taking the address of a single `u16` value, and pass it into an API, telling it that the pointed-to memory were 255 elements in size.

That needs to be solved: You will have to allocate a buffer large enough to hold the API's output first.

Converting a UTF-16 encoded string to a Rust `String` with its native encoding can be done using several different ways, such as [`String::from_utf16_lossy()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.from_utf16_lossy).

The following code roughly sketches out the approach:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut cb_buffer = 257_u32;

    // Create a buffer of the required size
    let mut buffer = Vec::<u16>::with_capacity(cb_buffer as usize);
    // Construct a `PWSTR` by taking the address to the first element in the buffer
    let lp_buffer = PWSTR(buffer.as_mut_ptr());

    let result = unsafe { GetUserNameW(lp_buffer, &mut cb_buffer) };

    // If the API returned success, and more than 0 characters were written
    if result.as_bool() && cb_buffer > 0 {
        // Construct a slice over the valid data
        let buffer = unsafe { slice::from_raw_parts(lp_buffer.0, cb_buffer as usize - 1) };

        // And convert from UTF-16 to Rust's native encoding
        let user_name = String::from_utf16_lossy(buffer);

        println!("User name: {}", user_name);
    }
}
```

Comment: The original code knew there were 2 bytes per element because it used `u16`.  Where does this new code control element type or account for element size?

Comment: @ben Rust has pretty solid type inference that, unlike C++', works across statements. `std::Vec` is a generic, but the type argument gets inferred from the following line, where a `PWSTR` gets constructed. That needs an argument of type `*mut u16`, hence the `std::Vec` knows, which type to store.

Comment: thank you very much, this one solved the problem, the address also stays the same
`lpbuffer: PWSTR(0x19de38d0fd0)
pcbbuffer: 255
lpbuffer: PWSTR(0x19de38d0fd0)
pcbbuffer: 5
User name: user`

Comment: @zab Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). I also rolled back your latest edit to the question. Putting *"SOLVED"* in the title is not how Stack Overflow communicates that a question was answered.